# Возможно ли в kotlin при использовании pow получить Long?

Tags: python, алгоритм, kotlin

Реализую алгоритм Карпа-Рабина на котлин. Написала функцию для вычисления хэша (код привожу ниже), и столкнулась с тем, что не могу получить Long при операции pow. Возможно ли это как-то сделать? Туплю немного, мб кто-то сталкивался. Заранее спасибо за все ответы!

```
    val hash  = d.toDouble().pow(patternLength - 1).toInt() % q // patternLength = 3, d = 40999999, q = 999999937
```

upd: немного поясню - при выполнении функции pow в котлин (без % даже) я получаю: 2147483647, та же функция в питон дает результат: 1680999918000001, который является верным

Comment: Так вы же пишете `toInt`

Comment: аааа, я слепая, думала что исправила XD спасибо большое!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы конвертируете результат в integer. Попробуйте использовать toLong()

```kotlin
import kotlin.math.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val d = 40999999
  val patternLength = 3
  val q = 999999937

  val hash  = d.toDouble().pow(patternLength - 1).toLong()// % q

  println(hash)
}
```

Возвращает 1680999918000001

Comment: да, именно так, почему-то подумала, что он только с Int работает, спасибо большое! :)